# Javascript: Hiding the stroke of a canvas object

Tags: javascript, canvas

This is a silly question, but how can I make the stroke of some canvas object invisible? Setting the width to 0 doesn't help (thin, but visible), and I don't know which color I should change the stroke to.

Comment: Set the alpha channel to zero maybe?

Comment: @MarkLinus trivial to answer if you had any clue

Comment: I'm sorry if this question is TOO simple, I didn't understand that it's forbidden.

Comment: @GadiA IMHO the question is fine.  The main complainer clearly had no idea what he was complaining about, and withdrew his comment (but probably not his down vote)

Comment: I don't really see why this was not a "real question", albeit a simple one. Quite obviously it is not "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical". It's a concrete "How to do X" question with a concrete "Do Y" solution (which was already given).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the opacity to zero will achieve that effect - i.e:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(1, 1, 1, 0)";
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/jYjmn/

Answer (score 1):

Setting the stroke to fully transparent as alnitak suggests is one way, but a slightly more appropriate (and more performant) way would be to simply not call stroke()!

The path (and all subpaths) will still exist if you don't call stroke and you can still fill or add to the path as you please.

Comment: For an existing object (e.g. Rect) how can I prevent stroke() from being called? Also note that I want to enable/disable the stroke as I choose.